# Dual boot POP OS with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I used this guide to install POP OS on my D drive[pop os](https://superuser.com/a/1334971/1132023). I have windows already installed on my C drive.

according to the guide grub did not install automatically, and was getting a blank screen while booting.
Now I'm trying to install grub manually and it failed again with the error 'grub-install command not found'
I made these  partitions:
1: 512 fat32 for efi (sda6)
2:8 GB for swap (sda7)
3: 100 GB for root (sda8)

If i want to manually reinstall grub again, where would I install it ?I'm confused between sda6 and sda8 ? 
and what would the correct procedure be ?